# Apache camel-jetty and activemq conflict in karaf?

Tags: jetty, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

I am having an issue in a clean karaf (4.0.3) installing both camel-jetty and activemq (for example, activemq-client or activemq-broker) together.  It doesn't matter the order the features are installed.  The second one hangs during install with no information displayed in the karaf log beyond that the install has begun.

Has anyone seen this before?  Is there a workaround?  I tried having the activemq-broker in it's own instance but then my app that uses both camel-jetty and jms still need to have the activemq connector initialized and thus I need to load activemq bundles/features.

Here is the output of both install separately, but when performed one after the other the 2nd always hangs the karaf instance.  There don't appear to be any bundles in common.

```
karaf@root()> feature:install activemq-client
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State  | Lvl | Version  | Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------
52 | Active |  80 | 5.12.1   | activemq-osgi
53 | Active |  80 | 3.3.0    | Commons Net
54 | Active |  80 | 2.4.2    | Apache Commons Pool
55 | Active |  80 | 1.0.1    | geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec
56 | Active |  80 | 1.1.1    | geronimo-jms_1.1_spec
57 | Active |  80 | 1.1.1    | geronimo-jta_1.1_spec
58 | Active |  80 | 3.4.6    | ZooKeeper Bundle
63 | Active |  80 | 2.2.11.1 | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jaxb-impl
70 | Active |  80 | 3.18.0   | Apache XBean :: Spring
71 | Active |  80 | 0.6.4    | JAXB2 Basics - Runtime
```

(Performed clean karaf launch in between installs to get bundle listings)

```
karaf@root()> feature:install camel-jetty
karaf@root()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State  | Lvl | Version | Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
55 | Active |  80 | 2.12.2  | camel-core
56 | Active |  80 | 2.12.2  | camel-http
57 | Active |  80 | 2.12.2  | camel-jetty
58 | Active |  80 | 2.12.2  | camel-karaf-commands
59 | Active |  80 | 1.8.0   | Commons Codec
63 | Active |  80 | 3.1.0.7 | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: commons-httpclient
```

Comment: did you try with the feature `camel-jetty9`? the default features of karaf4 use jetty9. and camel 2.12.2 is pretty old...

Comment: and as usual please ask at the apache mailinglist for such issues, they have a much bigger attention.